# Relative jump out of range by 0028h bytes

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

When I calculate the discount, I receive the message "(67)Relative leap out of range by 0028h bytes." I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. I've tried everything I've been taught, but I'm still not getting any results. Is there any missing or incorrect code, and how can it be fixed? P.S. I'm using DOSBox 0.74

```
TITLE   TOTAL_PAYMENT                       ; TITLE directive
.MODEL  SMALL                                   ;
.STACK  64                                  ;
.DATA
    checkOut    DB 10, 13,      'Total Check out: RM$'  ;
    total       DB 10, 13,      'Total Price: RM $' ;
    rebate      DB 10, 13,      'Discount: RM $'    ;
    membership  DB 10, 13,      'Membership(yes = y): $'        ;
    SST     DB 10, 13,      'SST: RM $'     ;
    totalPrice  DB  30                      ;
    divide      DB  100
    mulSST      DB  5
    mulDiscount DB  10

    temp        DB  ?                   ;
    remainderR  DB  ?                   ;
    remainderD  DB  ?                   ;
    tempRebate  DB  ?                   ;
    tempSST     DB  ?                   ;
    tempTotal   DB  ?                   ;


;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.CODE 
    MAIN    PROC    FAR                     ;

    MOV AX, @DATA                       ;
    MOV DS, AX                          ;

    MOV AH, 09H                         ; let user to input if the user is membership or not
    LEA DX, membership                      ; 
    INT 21H                         ;
    
    MOV AH, 01H                         ; 
    INT 21H                         ; 

    MOV temp, AL                        ; 
    
    MOV AH, 02H                         ;new line
    MOV DL, 0DH
    INT 21H
    MOV DL, 0AH
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 09H                         ;
    LEA DX, total                       ; display total
    INT 21H;                            ;

    MOV     AL, tempTotal                                   ; 
    AAM
    ADD     AX, 3030H                                       ; 
    PUSH    AX                                              ; 
    MOV     DL, AH                                          ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                             ;
    INT     21H
    POP     DX                                              ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                                         ; 
    INT     21H             

    MOV AH, 02H                         ;new line
    MOV DL, 0DH
    INT 21H
    MOV DL, 0AH
    INT 21H

    CMP temp, 79H                       ; if isMember get discount, else no discount
    jne C1                          ;

    MOV AH, 09H                         ;
    LEA DX, rebate                      ; display rebate message
    INT 21H                         ;


    MOV AL, totalPrice                      ;
    MUL mulDiscount                     ;
    DIV divide                          ;
    MOV tempRebate, AL                      ;
    MOV AH, 02H
    INT     21H                         ;
    

    MOV     AL, tempRebate                                  ; 
    AAM
    ADD     AX, 3030H                                       ; 
    PUSH    AX                                              ; 
    MOV     DL, AH                                          ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                             ;
    INT     21H
    POP     DX                                              ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                                         ; 
    INT     21H
    
                    

    MOV AH, 02H                         ;new line
    MOV DL, 0DH
    INT 21H
    MOV DL, 0AH
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 09H                         ;
    LEA DX, SST                         ; display sst
    INT 21H;                            ;

    MOV AL, totalPrice                      ;
    MUL mulSST                          ;
    DIV divide                          ;
    MOV tempSST, AL                     ;

    MOV     AL, tempSST                                     ; 
    AAM
    ADD     AX, 3030H                                       ; 
    PUSH    AX                                              ; 
    MOV     DL, AH                                          ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                             ;
    INT     21H
    POP     DX                                              ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                                         ; 
    INT     21H             
        
    MOV AH, 02H                         ;new line
    MOV DL, 0DH
    INT 21H
    MOV DL, 0AH
    INT 21H                         

    MOV AH, 09H                         ;
    LEA DX, checkOut                        ; display checkOut
    INT 21H                         ;

    MOV     AL, totalPrice                      ;
    MOV BL, tempRebate                      ;   
    SUB AL, BL                          ;
    MOV tempTotal, AL                       ;
                        
    
    MOV AL, tempTotal                       ;
    MOV BL, tempSST                     ;
    ADD AL, BL                          ;
    MOV     tempTotal, AL                       ;
    MOV AH, 02H
    INT     21H                         ;
    
    MOV     AL, tempTotal                                   ; 
    AAM
    ADD     AX, 3030H                                       ; 
    PUSH    AX                                              ; 
    MOV     DL, AH                                          ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                             ;
    INT     21H
    POP     DX                                              ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                                         ; 
    INT     21H


    JMP     endCode

;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C1:
    MOV AH, 09H                         ;
    LEA DX, SST                         ; display sst
    INT 21H;                            ;

    MOV AL, totalPrice
    MUL mulSST
    DIV divide
    MOV tempSST, AL


    MOV     AL, tempSST                                     ; 
    AAM
    ADD     AX, 3030H                                       ; 
    PUSH    AX                                              ; 
    MOV     DL, AH                                          ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                             ;
    INT     21H
    POP     DX                                              ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                                         ; 
    INT     21H             

    MOV AH, 02H                         ;new line
    MOV DL, 0DH
    INT 21H
    MOV DL, 0AH
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 09H                         ;
    LEA DX, checkOut                        ; display checkOut
    INT 21H                         ;

    MOV     AL, totalPrice
    MOV BL, tempSST
    ADD AL, BL
    MOV     tempTotal, AL
    MOV AH, 02H
    INT     21H                         ;

    MOV     AL, tempTotal                                   ; 
    AAM
    ADD     AX, 3030H                                       ; 
    PUSH    AX                                              ; 
    MOV     DL, AH                                          ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                             ;
    INT     21H
    POP     DX                                              ; 
    MOV     AH, 02H                                         ; 
    INT     21H
            

endCode:
    MOV AX, 4C00H                       ;
    INT 21H                         ;

    MAIN ENDP                           ;
END MAIN                                ;
```

Comment: Conditional jumps on 8086 had an 8-bit displacement and could only jump by about 127 bytes in either direction.  Check your listing file and look at the difference in addresses between `jne C1` and the `C1` label.  It may be out of range.  If so then rewrite with a reversed conditional jump over the unconditional one, e.g. `je next / jmp C1 / next:`

Comment: Besides telling us the emulator you are using (dosbox), please also state what *assembler* you are using (masm / tasm / fasm / ???), what version, and the exact command line or other steps you use to build your program.

Comment: This error means that you've got too much code between your `jne C1` and the destination. For most CPUs, there's a limit on how far you can conditionally branch. This limit is much larger on modern hardware, so much so that you'd probably never notice. But it's very strict on older machines like these.